# How does one control the output format of Eigenvectors[]?

Tags: matrix

Given the matrix:

```
m = {{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {Sin[x], -Cos[x]}}
```

Calculating the eigenvectors:

```
Eigenvectors[m]
```

gives the result:

```
{{Cot[x] - Csc[x], 1}, {Cot[x] + Csc[x], 1}}
```

But the eigenvectors can also be expressed as:

```
{{Cos[x/2], Sin[x/2]}, {-Sin[x/2], Cos[x/2]}}
```

How does one control the output type so mma gives the latter eigenvectors?

Comment: `Eigenvectors` does not normalize the vectors it obtains, when doing exact calculations (for say `Symbol`s and `Integer`s); but it does so for approximate calculations (e.g., for `Real`s). This information is findable in its F1 documentation, *Details and Options* part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

m = {{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {Sin[x], -Cos[x]}};

ev = Eigenvectors[m] // Map[Normalize, #] & //
   FullSimplify[#, 0 < x < Pi] & // Sort

(* {{Cos[x/2], Sin[x/2]}, {-Sin[x/2], Cos[x/2]}} *)
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you apply the `Sort` operation in the last step?

Comment: @CATrevillian - Prior to `Sort` the vectors were reversed from the form requested. `Sort` was used to put them in the requested order. It has no effect on the mathematical results.